# Angular 2.4.10 to 4.0.0 migration issue

Tags: angular

I tried to upgrade my application from Angular 2.4.10 to 4.0.0, using the command

```
"npm install @angular/common@next @angular/compiler@next @angular/compiler-cli@next @angular/core@next @angular/forms@next @angular/http@next @angular/platform-browser@next @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@next @angular/platform-server@next @angular/router@next @angular/animations@next --save".
```

Although there were no errors during "npm install", I received the following errors during "npm run build". I added "lib" to compilerOptions as directed in the changelog.

```
ERROR in [default]
File '/node_modules/bootstrap-loader/loader.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

ERROR in [default]
File '/node_modules/core-js/es6/index.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

ERROR in [default]
File '/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

ERROR in [default]
File '/node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

ERROR in [default]
File '/node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

ERROR in [default]
File '/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

ERROR in [default]
File '/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

ERROR in [default]
File '/node_modules/ts-helpers/index.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

ERROR in [default]
File '/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

ERROR in [default]    /node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/iterable_differs.d.ts:15:47
Cannot find name 'Iterable'.

ERROR in [default] /typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts:426:10
Interface 'NodeBuffer' incorrectly extends interface 'Uint8Array'.
  Types of property 'fill' are incompatible.
    Type '(value: any, offset?: number, end?: number) => Buffer' is not   assignable to type '(value: number, start?: number, end?: number) => this'.
      Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'this'.
```

"package.json"

```
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "4.0.0",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"angular2-toaster": "2.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"css-loader": "0.23.1",
"fullcalendar": "^2.7.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"intl": "1.2.4",
"jquery": "2.2.2",
"jquery-ui": "1.10.5",
"ng2-auto-complete": "^0.7.0",
"ng2-cookies": "^0.1.5",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
"node-sass": "^3.8.0",
"normalize.css": "^4.1.1",
"path-to-regexp": "^1.5.3",
"postcss": "^5.0.19",
"postcss-loader": "^0.8.2",
"primeng": "1.0.0-beta.15",
"primeui": "4.1.10",
"resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
"rxjs": "^5.0.1",
"sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"tether": "^1.2.0",
"typescript": "^2.1.5",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
"angular2-hmr": "~0.5.5",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "~0.17.0",
"babel-core": "^6.2.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple": "^6.7.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
"babel-preset-es2015-webpack": "^6.4.0",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
"bootstrap-loader": "1.0.10",
"codelyzer": "0.0.15",
"compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
"es6-promise-loader": "^1.0.1",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"file-loader": "^0.8.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
"http-server": "^0.9.0",
"imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
"istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"karma": "^0.13.22",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
"karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
"lodash": "^4.6.1",
"moment": "^2.11.2",
"node-sass": "3.7.0",
"npmconf": "2.1.2",
"parse5": "^2.1.5",
"phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
"protractor": "^3.2.2",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"remap-istanbul": "^0.6.3",
"resolve-url-loader": "^1.4.3",
"rimraf": "^2.5.2",
"sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
"source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
"ts-node": "^0.7.1",
"tslint": "^3.7.1",
"tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
"typedoc": "^0.3.12",
"typescript": "^2.1.5",
"typings": "^0.8.1",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack": "^1.12.14",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
"webpack-load-plugins": "^0.1.2",
"webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
"webpack-merge": "^0.12.0",
"webpack-validator": "^1.0.0-beta.4"
}
```

"tsconfig.json"

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib" : ["es2015.iterable.ts"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "src/custom_typings.d.ts",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "resolveGlobs": true,
    "forkChecker": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding additional libs to your tsconfig. On my project I have the following libs set for angular4:

```
"lib": [
  "es5",
  "es2015",
  "es2017",
  "dom",
  "scripthost"
]
```

If that doesn't work, as a workaround you can try using `"allowJs": true` inside your `compilerOptions` for your tsconfig.json, though I'd only consider that fix a workaround for something that is likely wrong with your repository.

Comment: Tried with `allowJs` and `lib` , still getting the same errors

Comment: How about `allowNonTsExtensions: true` inside your compiler options instead?

Comment: When I use `allowNonTsExtensions: true` instead of `allowJs`, I get the following error,

`./src/vendor.ts
Module build failed: Error: Final loader didn't return a Buffer or String`